# The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application (Azure Published app)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a test web application MVC, netcoreapp3.0 and I'm getting crazy with AD auth.

The appsettings.json

```
  {
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "Domain": "azurewebsites.net",
    "TenantId": "a6b08d54-xx",
    "ClientId": "4737e7b1-xx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Redirect URIs in the App regitrations:

https://cloud.azurewebsites.net:5001/signin-oidc

https://cloud.azurewebsites.net:5001/

logout:
https://cloud.azurewebsites.net:5001/signout-callback-oidc

Comment: Can you find the expected redirect url from the detailed error message ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Domain with the full name, say for ex. if your app name is **`stackoverflow-test`**

```
 "Domain": "https://stackoverflow-test.azurewebsites.net",
```

Comment: AADSTS50011: The reply address … does not match the reply addresses configured for the application...

Comment: i would suggest you to reconfigure the app

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your ASP.NET Core website to Azure App Services, usually `appsettings.json` is not deployed (you don’t want others to download your secrets). So you have to use Azure Portal `Application Settings` blade to upload your settings.

In the Azure portal, the reply URIs that you need to register on the `Authentication` page for your application need to match these URLs. For the two preceding configuration files, they would be `https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc`. The reason is that `applicationUrl` is `http://localhost:3110`, but sslPort is specified (44321). CallbackPath is `/signin-oidc`, as defined in `appsettings.json`.

For more details, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#configuration-files).

Comment: Hello, tank you for your reply. 
Do you mean in this way? 
[link to the screenshot](https://iquadsrl-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/andrea_gallazzi_iquad_it/EWv6x0jYHQNBlWH_wvoDXYMBXOJOogX9QGeRO99G0CiSAQ?e=rYUVuY)

Comment: Yes, configure redirect url in App registered and try again.

Comment: If you still have any problem, please feel free to let me know.